# Design Patterns : Question about "Types"

Tags: types, design-patterns

Would someone please explain to me what the below paragraph means?  This is a snippet from "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable OO software"

> Part of an object's interface may be characterized by one type, and other parts by other types.  Two objects of the same type need only share parts of their interfaces.  Interfaces can contain other interfaces as subsets. - Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable OO software, pg 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what the author is saying is that an object can implement more than one interface.  For instance, a "RaceCar" class might implement the "Drivable" interface while also implementing the "PotentiallyDangerous" interface.

In this example the RaceCar class might implement the "useNitrous()" method as declared by the "PotentiallyDangerous" interface and also implement the "startIgnition()" method declared by the "Drivable" interface.

Sorry, nothing against RaceCar enthusiasts, but it's the best car example I could get someone to edit for me.

---

**EDIT** drachenstern: thought you might appreciate the humorous edit, feel free to revert.

Comment: +1, although so far my housemate's pit bull has been quite friendly. ;)

Comment: Lol, I've personally seen things go horribly wrong, but I've also heard very passionate owners strongly assert that they trust their companions with their lives.

Comment: @drachenstern - Lol, no this is a lot better and will evoke less emotion from dog ownwers! I just couldn't think of a good Car adjective at the moment :)  Great abstraction :)

Comment: @jmort253, if only i had been original and derived it myself ;) ... You'll notice it was effectively your post ;)

Comment: @drachenstern - I was actually thinking about taking your edit a step further and replacing RaceCar with [[INSERT_NOUN_HERE]] and Driveable with [[INSERT_ADJECTIVE_HERE]], etc... but I think seeing a concrete example helps people initially understand the concepts.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually where textbooks go wrong, I say leave it or revert it, don't edit it further ;)

Answer (score 6):

To understand what this means you first need to remember that the [Gang of Four](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) wrote this book back in 1994, when the vast majority of programmers in the world were not using (and had never heard of) object-oriented programming.

Gamma, Helm, Johnson and Vlissides are basically introducing the concept of interfaces here. The idea is that a piece of code that interacts with an object doesn't really need to understand how the underlying implementation happens, and that two different objects can have the same interface but have different implementations. We do that all the time today with interfaces in Java and Objective-C.

But they go further, and imply that an object may have several interfaces, one from one type (or interface), and one from another. You can do this explicitly with multiple inheritance in C++, or with multiple interfaces in Java, or just by using the same naming convention.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  I also think it's great to point out the age of these concepts as it helps put them in perspective.  While many technologies today are quickly outdated, conceptual ideas such as this seem to stand the test of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, he a means [Composite Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) created by a class which which has two parents providing different interfaces each useful to the object created. Look for the Java Example in the referenced link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be describing the ability for classes to implement multiple interfaces.

For example, a `Car` and a `Motorcycle` might both implement `iVehicle`, but they each may have other methods and members that are unique to each other.  For example, the `Car` might implement `iWindowedVehicle` whereas the `Motorcycle` would not.

One part of the quotation which may be misleading is "Two objects of the same **type** need only share..." (emphasis mine).  I assume they are using the word type there loosely, to mean, two objects which implement the same interface (like `Car` and `Motorcycle` both implement `iVehicle`, as opposed to the same actual class, like two `Cars` in my example.

Comment: I tend to like using adjectives as naming conventions for Interfaces.  For example, implements Taggable, or implements Serializable, or implements Runnable are some examples from Java.  I'd suggest changing iVehicle to something like "Driveable" or "Runnable".

Comment: the adjective seems like a good convention.  Perhaps that's enough to distinguish it as an interface, but I do like it being obvious with a prefix.  Here are some MSDN guidelines on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Comment: @pcloadletter - Most of the Java developers I know use the I prefix, but that's just because it's what our organization has done from the beginning.  Using adjectives in Java just seems to make more sense to me because it's what the pro's use (Sun/Oracle), and it's more consistent.  You don't see classes prefixed with a C or methods prefixed with an M.  CMyClass, for instance, would raise some eyebrows, but it would be more consistent with IMyClass.  I do like that adjectives help describe a class's purpose.  A Driveable Car as opposed to a Salvaged Car tells me more about it's status.

Comment: @jmort253  That's all well and good.  Like I said, I like your adjectives, but I think a case can be made for making it (more) obvious when something is an interface.  There aren't dozens of different kinds of usually-uppercased user-defined labels, and I think there is merit for some organizations to add a prefix to help distinguish the two.